# I need prevent and alert users whenever their entry is a duplicate in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm managing a tracker in google sheets, where users should enter new IDs in column A.
I need to prevent them, as well as alert them, whenever their entry is a duplicate (so the ID already exists in column A).
Data validation isn't a good option. How should I go about this?

Comment: You can highlight duplicates with conditional formatting https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-highlight-duplicates/

Comment: Thanks but it's not good enough in this case. I need to actually prevent and alert, or at least push an alert pop up with explanation.

Comment: To a degree it can be done with `onEdit()` trigger (in a script). It will watch any editions in some column and after every change to search for duplicates (and show a window, for example). But it will work quite slowly if there are several hundreds cells and it sometimes doesn't work with pasting.

Comment: Would you have an idea for a script? Forgot to mention - I'm a first time user

Comment: It looks like you already have two worked solutions that implement about the same idea (`onEdit()`). It makes no sense to me to make yet another variant unless these solutions somehow don't work for you.

Comment: unfortunately the onedit one alerts and deletes all entries regardless of duplications, the onmyedit one works ok, but shoots the message always twice. I'd appreciate if you could contribute but appreciate it even if you dont!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var value = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()
  var r = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()
  var c = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn()
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if(value!=="" && c==1 && r>2 && sheetName == "Sheet2"){ // change condition before testing
    var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).flat() // change rage according to requrments
    if(data.indexOf(value)>-1){
      e.range.setValue("")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: NICE! But it's deleting every entry atm, even non duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: It's exactly what I need, it's just deleting all entries regardless of duplications.

Comment: @YuriKhristich it's not working fine. It's simply the closest solution so far.

Comment: I think the code contains the little mistake. Try to change the line `if(data.indexOf(value)>-1){` with `if(data.indexOf(value)!=data.lastIndexOf(value)){`

Answer (score 2):

we do with data validation with formula

```
=countif($B$2:$B,B2)>1
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really work in google sheets. I.e., if they copy-paste a value, the data validation will not reject the entry. It will only reject input once they type it in. This does work in excel, but not in google sheets (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: @Franco it will reject the entry.

Comment: @TheMaster only when typed manually. If its an index(match or even a copy paste this will flag it, but won't reject it and won't show an error pop up.

Answer (score 0):

#### Clear and alert duplicates

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value !== null) {
    e.source.toast("Flag1")
    let u = [];
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat().forEach(el => {
      if(!~u.indexOf(el)) {
        u.push(el)
      } else {
        e.source.toast("Your have created a duplicate");
        e.range.clearContent();
      }
    }); 
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Super cool, but unfortunately it's not working for me at all

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onMyEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: You cannot run these the script editor

Comment: I tested it.  It works.  If it's not working for you perhaps you need to change something like the sheet name.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge- but other "Sheet0" that I had changed, what else is there to change? And where should I run this instead of the editor?

Comment: You simply determine what page you wish is to run on and then load and save it and go to the page and make edits.   I made this one an installable so you will also have to create and installable trigger for onMyEdit.  Since you going to run other functions that my required permissions then you will need to use an installable trigger which you can make from the script editor triggers menu.